# Qt5 QtChart drop vertical lines while using QScatterSeries

Tags: qt5, qtcharts

When I am using QScatterSeries, I can very easily draw point at (x, y). However, instead of points I would like to draw short lines, like in the figure below.[image] How can I get about doing so?

I tried using RectangleMarker, but it just draws a fat square. I would prefer a thin line about 2px wide and 20px in height.

Is there a way I can add custom marker shapes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the code and the settings I use to transform my points into lines :

```
//create scatter series to draw point
m_pSeries1 = new QtCharts::QScatterSeries();
m_pSeries1->setName("trig");
m_pSeries1->setMarkerSize(100.0);

//draw a thin rectangle (50 to 50)
QPainterPath linePath;
linePath.moveTo(50, 0);
linePath.lineTo(50, 100);
linePath.closeSubpath();

//adapt the size of the image with the size of your rectangle
QImage line1(100, 100, QImage::Format_ARGB32); 
line1.fill(Qt::transparent);
QPainter painter1(&line1);
painter1.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
painter1.setPen(QColor(0, 0, 0));
painter1.setBrush(painter1.pen().color());
painter1.drawPath(linePath);

//attach your image of rectangle to your series
m_pSeries1->setBrush(line1);
m_pSeries1->setPen(QColor(Qt::transparent));

//then use the classic QtChart pipeline...
```

You can play the marker size, the dimension of the image and the drawing pattern in the painter to adapt the size and shape of the rectangle to obtain a line.

[image]

In the picture, it's the black line. As you can see you can repeat the process for other series.
Keep in mind that you **cannot** use the openGL acceleration:

```
m_pSeries0->setUseOpenGL(true);
```

My work is based on the QtCharts/QScatterSeries example : [QScatterSeries example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtcharts-scatterchart-example.html)

Hope it will help you.

Florian

Comment: Brilliant...! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton. I had tried this method, but had failed to use an image with the size equal to the markerSize because of which the lines were not rendering properly.

Comment: Nice but there is no other workaround ? I mean a vertical line should be a basic plotting feature.